# How can I deserialize an enum with an optional internal tag?

Tags: rust, serde

I use Serde to deserialize a custom configuration file written in YAML. The file can contain definitions of various kinds that I represent as internally tagged enums:

```yaml
OfKindFoo:
  kind: Foo
  bar: bar;
  baz: baz;

OfKindQux:
  kind: Qux
  quux: qux;
```

I represent it in Rust like this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "kind")]
enum Definition {
    Foo(Foo),
    Qux(Qux),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Qux {
    quux: String,
}
```

I want the user to be able to omit the `kind` field completely, and when it is omitted Serde should default to deserializing it as `Foo`.

I started to implement `Deserialize` on `Definition`. I'm trying to deserialize it as a map and look for the `kind` key and return a respective enum variant based on this key and whether it is present.

I need to somehow "forward" the deserialization of other map fields to `Foo::deserialize` or `Bar::deserialize`, respectively. `fn deserialize` only takes one argument which is `Deserializer`. Is there a way to "convert" the map into a deserializer or otherwise get a deserializer that "starts" on that particular map?

I cannot use [`#[serde(other)]`](https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#other) because it returns `Err` for a missing tag. Even if it didn't, the documentation states that `other` can only be applied to a "unit variant",  a variant not containing any data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mark the main enum as `untagged` and add tags to the sub-structs that do have a tag (this feature [is not documented](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1684), but was added deliberately and so seems likely to stay). The variant without a tag should be declared after the other ones though, as serde will try to deserialize the variants in declared order with `#[serde(untagged)]`. Also note that if in your actual code, the variants and the structs have different names, or you're using `#[serde(rename)]`, with this, the names of the structs are what matters for (de)serialization, not the variant names. All that applied to your example:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Definition {
    Qux(Qux),
    Foo(Foo), // variant that doesn't have a tag is the last one
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    baz: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "kind")]
// if you want the tag to be "qux" instead of "Qux", do
// #[serde(rename = "qux")]
// here (or add `, rename = "qux"` to the previous serde attribute)
struct Qux {
    quux: String,
}
```

Comment: As @seyed [explains in his answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74544853/162354), this does not work if multiple structs have an identical required structure (can also happen e.g. due to defaults for many fields).

Answer (score 1):

If structs have the same shape or all the fields are optional, [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61219284/896465) won't work and will be deserialized to the first kind. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5390c509c26eb787314f9b417c7e053)

With the [monostate](https://crates.io/crates/monostate) crate it can be fixed.

```rust
use monostate::MustBe;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Action {
    Hi(Hi),
    Bye(Bye),
    Unknown(Unknown),
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Hi {
    kind: MustBe!("Hi"),
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Bye {
    kind: MustBe!("Bye"),
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Unknown {
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn tests() {
        assert_eq!(
            Action::Hi(Hi { kind: Default::default(),  name: "John".to_string() }),
            serde_json::from_str::<Action>(r#"{"kind": "Hi", "name": "John"}"#).unwrap()
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Action::Bye(Bye { kind: Default::default(), name: "John".to_string() }),
            serde_json::from_str::<Action>(r#"{ "kind": "Bye", "name": "John" }"#).unwrap()
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Action::Unknown(Unknown {  }),
            serde_json::from_str::<Action>(r#"{ "name": "John" }"#).unwrap()
        );
        assert_eq!(
            Action::Unknown(Unknown {  }),
            serde_json::from_str::<Action>(r#"{}"#).unwrap()
        );
    }

}
```